# How to pass a directory path to BitmapFactory.decodeFile

Tags: android

Currently I can pass the path to an image in the sdcard. Now I want to pass a path to a folder(to the same function BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path)) so that all the images in the folder can be displayed using

```
image.setImageBitmap(img);
```

Basically, I want to display all the images in the selected folder as a slideshow, one after the other. Any help / pointers on this?

Comment: First, are you comfortable displaying a single image from the sdcard onto an imageview? If not, start there. Second, you must decode each image separately; you can't just give setImageBitmap an entire folder. Third, you might want to check out the Gallery layout.

Comment: yes, I'm currently able to display a single image from the sdcard onto the imageview. shd i call bitmapfactory.decodefile for each image in the folder? any link you have which u think will help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for here. You've asked a very general question. I think what would be best for you is to use a [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) widget.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is getting URLs or paths to all the images. I can think of two alternatives.

1) List all files in whatever folder you are looking for and get the ones of the right type. You can use listFiles to get all the files in a folder:

```
File files[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
```

and string split or substring to get the extension

```
string filename = file[i].getName(); 
int pos = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
string ext = filename.substring(pos);
```

2) You can use a content resolver and get the images straight from the Android MediaStore. This solution would be more robust. Search for how to use the MediaStore if you want to use this.

Second step is to use BitmapFactory to get all the bitmaps you need. Yes, you will need to call decodeResource once for each bitmap you get from a file.

Comment: OK, followed your steps. Took the first one as I dont have any idea abt the MediaStore. I didnt understand the second step properly. I'm using a bitmapfactory and im able to display one image successfully. What shd I do to display series of images in a row (like a slideshow)?